# certbot-auto Debug fails at pip No module Python

Tags: python, lets-encrypt

I tried to debug "`certbot-auto --debug`" and it stuck on the following:

```
Installing Python packages...
/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/python: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp.gK69dFvmow/pipstrap.py", line 177, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/tmp.gK69dFvmow/pipstrap.py", line 149, in main
    pip_version = StrictVersion(check_output([python, '-m', 'pip', '--version'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I was actually trying to update the SSL certificate using the command

```
sudo certbot-auto --nginx -d domain.com  -d www.domain.com
```

But it failed on this,

```
Creating virtual environment...
Installing Python packages...
/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/python: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp.kOxEgPvxDL/pipstrap.py", line 177, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/tmp.kOxEgPvxDL/pipstrap.py", line 149, in main
    pip_version = StrictVersion(check_output([python, '-m', 'pip', '--version'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have installed python 3.7 (made it default) and 2.7 (by default)

I have installed python 3.7 thinking it may resolve the issue but no use. Then I made python 3.7 as default but its no use as well. But again it seems to be having no use.

This is my client's web server and they don't to upgrade the OS version. Please give suggestions on the existing server

How to fix this issue?

Comment: "I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" Sound like it's time to upgrade.

Comment: I can't upgrade my client's website server. They don't want an upgrade. Please give suggestions on the existing sever.

Comment: it shows problem with running `pip` so run the same command manually to get more information - `/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/python -m pip --version`

Comment: don't set 3.7 as default - some functions in old Linux/Ubuntu use 2.7 and may not run with 3.7

Comment: okay. I will reset it. Do you have any solution for the issue I originally asked?

Comment: I have no solution because there is no information what is real problem. Maybe if you run `/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/python -m pip --version` then you get more information. I would try to install again `pip`.

Comment: [how to install pip using get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: This command give me: `/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/python: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed.`    I am starting to think that `pip` is not installed here

Comment: Just checked again, I have `# pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)` this pip version installed. I remember I updated it the last time I was looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this issue. I am successfully able to fix it using the solution here: [PIP error with certbot-auto](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/pip-error-with-certbot-auto/88200/6). For a reference, I am adding the solution here.